# Trying to add images to a table containing products

Tags: php, html

For my final school project, I need to make a working webshop and I'm doing pretty well. The only thing that's bugging me is that I don't know how to add images to a table in PHP. I have 2 PHP files that work together. One is called products.php and contains arrays of the products in my webshop. There are a total of 7 products in this file, each one having a name, price, menutext and description. I would like to add one image to each of these products in this file. I can't change it in other file because it takes it's information from products.php... Here is a part of code from products.php:

```
$products = array(
1 => array(
    'name' => 'Potza Salami',
    'price' => 5.99,
    'menutext' => 'Tomatensaus, kaas en salami.',
    'description' => 'Ingrediënten: tomatensaus, kaas en salami.',
    'img' => print(<img src=images/salami.jpg width='300' length='300'>)
```

The img part doesn't seem to work for me. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: 'print(<img src="images/salami.jpg" width="300" length="300">)'

Comment: Are you getting a parse error? Also, why are you calling `print` there?

Comment: I was wondering that too. You don't really need the print.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to print the img part

```
$products = array(
1 => array(
    'name' => 'Potza Salami',
    'price' => 5.99,
    'menutext' => 'Tomatensaus, kaas en salami.',
    'description' => 'Ingrediënten: tomatensaus, kaas en salami.',
    'img' => '<img src="images/salami.jpg" width="300" length="300">'
)
);
```

Comment: @TomRassaerts, no problem. If your problem has been solved, please select the answer. So, no more developers spend time on this question